# Issue when writing output to file in Powershell

Tags: powershell

first time asking a question here. I am new to Powershell and trying to use it to get the last write time of several files with paths I have saved in a .txt file. I have to do this for ~9000 CAD files and am currently practicing. Below is what I have gotten to work, but when I try and write it to a file it gives me an error and I don't know how to fix it.

This is what I have working:

```
> foreach($line in get-content
> c:\users\jcuthbertson\desktop\filesforgettingdate.txt) {
> if($line -match $regex){
> -join((get-item $line).lastwritetime,",", (get-item $line).name)}}
6/24/2020 11:38:42 AM,Book1.xlsx
6/30/2020 4:16:47 PM,Book2.xlsx
7/10/2020 7:37:31 AM,dwg_vwx_mcd files.xlsx
7/7/2020 9:43:30 AM,Program cleaning flow sequences.xlsx
7/9/2020 8:49:14 AM,vxw paths commas.xlsx
```

But when I add the "out-file" command it gives me and error saying there is an empty pipe

```
> foreach($line in get-content
> c:\users\jcuthbertson\desktop\filesforgettingdate.txt) {
> if($line -match $regex){
> -join((get-item $line).lastwritetime,",", (get-item $line).name)}} | out-file c:\users\jcuthbertson\desktop\testdatawrite.txt
At line:3 char:68
+ ... get-item $line).lastwritetime,",", (get-item $line).name)}} | out-fil ...
+                                                                 ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: This is because your `foreach` script block is not actually sending anything to the pipeline. It is the code inside that has that capability. You either need to move your `Out-File` command with `-Append` to inside of your `foreach` or capture the output before sending to `Out-File`. You can use a variable or sub-expression operator `$()`. Variable -> `$var = foreach ($line in ...) {...}; $var | out-file`. Sub-expression -> `$(foreach ($line in ..) {..}) | Out-File`.

Comment: Also check out PowerShell ISE. You dont need to develop on the Powershell Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior occurs because the `foreach` script block is not actually outputting anything to the pipeline. The pipeline capable output occurs from the `-join` operator inside the `foreach` loop. This leaves you with a few options for piping data into [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7).

**Option 1: Pipe the results of `-join` into `Out-File`**

```
foreach($line in get-content c:\users\jcuthbertson\desktop\filesforgettingdate.txt) {
    if($line -match $regex){
        -join ((get-item $line).lastwritetime,",",(get-item $line).name) |
            Out-File c:\users\jcuthbertson\desktop\testdatawrite.txt -Append
    }
}
```

Note the use of the `-Append` switch to not overwrite the file with each iteration.

**Option 2: Capture the outputs in a variable and pipe the variable contents**

```
$output = foreach($line in get-content c:\users\jcuthbertson\desktop\filesforgettingdate.txt) {
    if($line -match $regex){
        -join ((get-item $line).lastwritetime,",",(get-item $line).name)
    }
}
$output | Out-File c:\users\jcuthbertson\desktop\testdatawrite.txt
```

**Option 3: Force the `foreach` script block to be an expression using subexpression [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7) `$()`**

```
$(foreach($line in get-content c:\users\jcuthbertson\desktop\filesforgettingdate.txt) {
    if($line -match $regex){
        -join ((get-item $line).lastwritetime,",",(get-item $line).name)
    }
}) | Out-File c:\users\jcuthbertson\desktop\testdatawrite.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining! I went with option 2 and it worked perfectly! I will remember that in the future:)

Answer (score 3):

This is in addition to [AdminOfThings good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840342/4749264).  If you're new to PowerShell I thought you might like to see another option.  You can use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet Which allows you to leverage the pipeline straight through.

```
$File = 'c:\temp\Test_Input.txt'

Get-Content $File |
ForEach-Object{
    If( $_ -match $RegEx ) {
        $Item = Get-Item $_
        $Item.LastWriteTime, $Item.Name -join ','
    }
} |
Out-File c:\temp\test_output.txt -Append
```

Maybe it's a matter of preference and circumstance but by embracing the pipeline it's going to be more memory efficient.  Don't get me wrong memory isn't usually an issue, but there is a difference between collecting objects up front either by sub-expression `$(...)` or by storing in a variable.  Options 2 & 3 in the previous answer store the whole output before writing it to the file.  Also, Option 1 from the previous answer is opening and closing the file repeatedly.

It's also unnecessary to run `Get-Item` multiple times, hence I introduced `$Item`.  But, that could've been adapted in any example.

Let me know if that's helpful.

Comment: That was very helpful thanks! Examples for me to reference later are always beneficial.